# The views didn't return an HttpResponse object. It returned None instead

Tags: django, django-views

I am trying to make my new form and in that process i have encountered this issue of The view myapp.views.contact didn't return an HttpResponse object.
It returned None instead.Please help me out

The problem is in return render function and have no clue of how solve this HttpResponse error

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.http import HttpResponse
from .forms import ContactForm,SnippetForm

def contact(request):

    if request.method == 'POST':

        form = ContactForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():


            name= form.cleaned_data['name']
            email=form.cleaned_data['email']

            print(name,email)

            form = ContactForm()
            return render(request,'form.html',{'form':form})

def snippet_detail(request):

    if request.method == 'POST':

        form = SnippetForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():


            print("VALID")
            form = SnippetForm()
            return render(request,'form.html',{'form': form})
            #form.save()
```

## Create your views here.

The error message is in the browser and the question is itself a error message.

Answer (score 2):

There might be form error

You need to handle form error case.

```
if request.method == 'POST':

    form = ContactForm(request.POST)
    if form.is_valid():


        name= form.cleaned_data['name']
        email=form.cleaned_data['email']

        print(name,email)

        form = ContactForm()
        return render(request,'form.html',{'form':form})

    else:
       return render(request,'form.html',{'form':form})
 else:
    form = ContactForm()
    return render(request,'form.html',{'form':form})
```

hope it helps. refer [this](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/forms/)

Comment: error what the terminal is throwing is the HttpResponse!

Comment: Internal Server Error: /
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/rehan/my_env/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py", line 34, in inner
    response = get_response(request)
  File "/home/rehan/my_env/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 126, in _get_response
    "returned None instead." % (callback.__module__, view_name)
ValueError: The view myapp.views.contact didn't return an HttpResponse object. It returned None instead.